# How to change controllers/views using a menu with codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying load a view or controller when the user presses a link on the menu.  So if the menu had one button on it which said create new form I would want when pressed to load up a view or controller that creates a new form so it would be newform.php.

This is my menu view.

```
<div id="SideNave" class="sidenav">
<a href="<?php echo (base_url('temp'));?>">Create New</a>
<a href="#">Verification</a>
<a href="#">Accounting</a>
<a href="#">Order Fulfillment</a>
<a href="#">Order History</a>
<a href="#">Maintenance</a>
<a href="#">Reporting</a>
</div>
```

I have tried the base_url but I get a call to undefined function on the base_url

I have tried to change the base url but again no luck there.  I wasnt sure where to go from here.

Comment: Do you have any examples of the code you already tried?

Comment: I have added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is redirecting through base_url using temp.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>newForm">Create New</a>
```

The newForm in the anchor tag is the controller name where you are calling your newform view.
And make sure you have set the base_url in config.php
Hope this helps!!

Comment: So i am getting a 404 The requested URL /~******/fdoe/html/newForm was not found on this server.  I have it set up like you said and I do have the base_url set up $config['base_url'] = 'http://********/~*******/fdoe/html';

Comment: Have you created a controller that is redirecting to the newform.php view???
And in this
$config['base_url'] = 'http://********/~*******/fdoe/html' , why have you mentioned /html in that. I think thats where you are wrong.
See this is how i have done: 
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';

Comment: fdoe/MainPage was not found on this server.  Is what I get if I do that.  I have thought about it before and I should have said that in the post.  If I give a more direct path I do not have to permissions to access that path.

Comment: Did you check your .htaccess file?? I think there must be the problem. Because according to what you are saying if its not redirecting to the main page which i'm assuming is present in your project folder, then there must be some issue there.

Comment: I got it.  You and the other guy was right if you combined your answers.  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>html/index.php/MainPage">Create New</a>  That got me to the new page.

Comment: You do need the html is important to have in the base_url because of security reasons.  Anyways thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It was my pleasure helping you! :)

Answer (score -1):

> index.php/controller/function">Create
>   New